# sqlconnection error

Tags: mysql, c#, .net

Hola a todos se que para mucho y sobre todo para las personas veteranas en c# esta pregunta será muy sencilla pero no encuentro (bueno no comprendo) como hacer una clase estática de conexión para retornar una conexión con la base de datos ya que he trabajado siempre con VS2019 pero me toca hacer una conexión en VS2017 con el .net framework 4.7.2

```
        public static SqlConnection getConexion() {
        string database, server, puerto, user, password;

        database = "datosprueba";
        server = "localhost";
        puerto = "3306";
        user = "root";
        password = "1234";

        string consulta = "Database =" + database + "; Data Source ="  + server + "; Port =" + puerto + "; User Id =" + user + "; Password ="+ password;

        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(consulta);

        return conexion;
    }
```

Me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se que tengo algo mal en la sentencia pero no se como escribirla en esta versión agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Prueba con `MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(consulta);`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se encuentra en el connection string, si estas usando .NET Framework Data Provider para MySql con seguridad estándar y un puerto especifico, deberías de usar el siguiente template:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Te dejo un enlace que te puede ayudar para cuando tengas problemas con las cadenas de conexión.
https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta igual puedes encontrar el connectionstring que necesitas en la pagina que te compartí.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que tú problema está en la biblioteca que usas para conectarte a la base de datos, cuál usas? Dependiendo el proveedor de datos , la cadena de conexión puede ser distinta. Te recomiendo usar el de Microsoft

Comment: Esto queda mejor como comentario a la pregunta que como respuesta.